# Creating an IP "whitelist" for iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm using a cellular modem/router that has iptables. There is also a clunky webUI that allows simple adjustments, such as turning on WAN ICMP/HTTPS/SSH. I clearly don't want those ports wide up and publicly facing. But I would like to have remote management access to this device from a predetermined whitelist of addresses. There are possibly up to 10 addresses, and some are IP ranges/subnets. I have tested this with a single address with a rule like

```
-A HTTPS_WAN_INPUT -i ppp0 -s x.x.x.x -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

But the prospect of writing rules like that 10 times and for each port/protocol seems clunky, so I'm writing to see if there is a better way to do this? Can I create a $WHITELIST variable that contains all the addresses and use that in the -s? Or can I apply the whitelist to something further up the chain, such as one of the policies?

I'm just trying to figure out if there is a more elegant way of allowing remote access to a set of IPs without writing 10 different lines for each rule.

Comment: How are you doing this - it's easy enough to write a script, or even a for each loop.

Comment: SSH to the CLI of the device, to custom embedded Linux distro (custom to the vendor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have only 2 options (or a combination)... but one is slightly more risky than the other.  Keep in mind that the `src` field also accepts subnets.. i.e. 192.168.1.0/24.

First, *If* your iptables/kernel is built with the `iprange` module, you can use it to specify a range of IPs instead of just 1-2... but you cannot provide a "list" of ips.  Example:

```
-A HTTPS_WAN_INPUT -i ppp0 -m iprange --src-range x.x.x.x-y.y.y.y -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Second, you can setup a new target specific target including "whitelisted" IPs just to keep things clean. Example:

```
iptables -N RemoteManagement
iptables -P RemoteManagement DROP
iptables -A -A HTTPS_WAN_INPUT -i ppp0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j RemoteManagement
```

... and for each IP you want to permit...

```
iptables -I RemoteManagement -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT
```

This allows you to keep your rules a bit cleaner, and be able to simply delete IPs/add IPs as needed.  Of course, if you have the `iprange` module available, you can also specify ranges in the RemoteManagement chain.  You could also reuse this same chain in other scenarios where it applies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I like the second option quite a bit. The VMs I want to whitelist  are all over the place/non-contiguous, so the range doesn't really help cutdown on the number of entries. But it seems like setting up a custom rule once with the list, and then jumping to that for each rule makes sense. Is there a way to simplify things and have all incoming traffic jump through that rule so if I don't want to modify the jump for existing rules, the traffic would still be filtered? Can you do that with prerouting?? or does -j ACCEPT override?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is being asked... with the example above (2nd) only the traffic that matches is passed over to the RemoteManagement target for further testing.  Once any decision is made on traffic, there is no way to override it.  (`ACCEPT`/`DROP`/`REJECT`/etc...)  There is one special rule called `RETURN` which will basically return back to the parent chain and continue processing.  It is unwise to rely heavily on `RETURN` rules, because they can cause a lot of overhead.

Comment: That answered my questions. I guess I was asking if there was a way to modify ACCEPT, but this clearly accomplishes what I want. Only now, I found out, my IoT device doesn't save IPTABLES  on reboot so I have a new problem :( Thanks for your help.

Comment: I generally like to do the iptables rules in the interface config files. (`iptables-save`/`iptables-restore` in interfaces file up/down statements for deb flavors... I'm sure there is something similar for RHEL flavors, but I'm not much of a RHEL fan.)  Stuff like that should be automagic.  I really hate the idea of having interfaces brought online without the correct firewall rules applied.